# Android : How do I integrate whatsapp calling

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to direct call to a number by whatsapp from another application?

I have tried to redirect for messaging by using  below code  and is working fine.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));`
```

Is there any similar way for calling ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure as I have not test this but hope this will work,

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
 callIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

And don't forget below permission in menifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Not working with error: No Activity found to handle the Intent.

Comment: Whatsapp does not have ACTION_CALL filter